# Moving Items from one html page to another

Tags: javascript, html, function, frontend, shopping-cart

how to move an item in a list from one html page to another without or with using localStorage.set-getItem

I am makimg an e commerce website. When my client clicks the "add" button of an item, I want that Item to move to the shopping cart. The problem is that the shopping cart is a different html page (not in the same maine html page)

I tried to ust this, yet it did not work

```
Let list = document.querySelectorAll(".list .item")
    list.forEach(item => { item.addEventListener("click", function(item) { if(event.target.classList.contains("add")) {
document.querySelector(".listcart").appendChild(item)
   }
  })
})
```

(The list is in the main html page, and the listcart is in another html page)
It worked when I put the listcart in the same main page, but when I moved it to another one, the code stopped working, yet there is no errors in the console

So guys do you have a slution for this?

Comment: In order to make an ecommerce website, you will probably need more than a front end. You might want to look into a site builder with ecommerce capabilities such as WordPress, WIX, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to make a cart the best practice without using any Javascript frameworks is to use local storage.

However, if you still want to do it without using local storage, you can pass the item ID as a URL parameter when the user clicks the "add" button, and retrieve the item data on the shopping cart page using JavaScript. For example, you can redirect the user to the shopping cart page with a URL like cart.html?item=123, where 123 is the ID of the selected item. On the shopping cart page, you can use JavaScript to retrieve the item parameter from the URL and display the corresponding item.

**In the source page**

```js
// Assume we have a list of items with IDs and names
let items = [
  { id: 1, name: "Item 1" },
  { id: 2, name: "Item 2" },
  { id: 3, name: "Item 3" }
];

let list = document.querySelectorAll(".list .item");
list.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains("add")) {
      // Get the item ID from the data-id attribute
      let itemId = event.target.parentElement.dataset.id;
      // Redirect the user to the shopping cart page with the item ID as a parameter
      window.location.href = `cart.html?item=${itemId}`;
    }
  });
});
```

In the cart Page.

```js
// Retrieve the item ID from the URL parameter
let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
let itemId = urlParams.get("item");

// Find the item with the matching ID
let selectedItem = items.find(item => item.id == itemId);

// Display the selected item in the shopping cart
let cartList = document.querySelector(".listcart");
let cartItem = document.createElement("div");
cartItem.classList.add("item");
cartItem.dataset.id = selectedItem.id;
cartItem.innerHTML = `<span>${selectedItem.name}</span>`;
cartList.appendChild(cartItem);
```